# Multiple annotations Dart Lang for a variable

Tags: dart

I have been loving Dart lang since started using this month. I have a simple question but still cant seem to find how to do it.

So i know i can do a single annotation in Dart lang:

```
final DocumentSnapshot project;
```

but how can i archive with multiple annotations. Below seems to not work.

```
final DocumentSnapshot, DocumentReference project;
```

Comment: What would you need that for? The variable `project` can only have one type.

Comment: Im using `project` as a constructor property, so i want to receive either DocumentSnapshot or DocumentReference to this variable. Probably my logic is not ok.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for union types. Dart doesn't support that yet.

You can either use a common supertype of the types `DocumentSnapshot` and `DocumentReference`. If there are no more specific common supertypes, you can use `Object` which is the common supertype of all types.

You can also use `dynamic` which allows you to call methods and access properties without casting to a concrete type.

Another alternative is to use two fields instead.

Comment: thanks for the reply, as i suspected my code was not ok. Normally only DocumentSnapshot was needed. Anyway was good to know your reply!